# How to translate strings in (programmatically created) custom module?

Tags: 8, blocks, i18n-l10n

I've (programmatically) created a custom module which includes a block with a string wrapped in the $this->t() function. How or where can I extract this translation file?

In Drupal 7 I would extract a translation file of the custom module, but the POTX module is not ported to Drupal 8 yet.

```
public function build() {
  return array(
    '#markup' => $this->t('How and where can I translate this string?'),
  );
}
```

Comment: @4k4 I don't think that's the answer I'm looking for. The 'Translate Interface' option only allows to export one file with all translations. I'm looking for a way to extract the translations for one specific (custom) module, like in Drupal 7 would be done with POTX.

Answer (score 1):

Potx is not yet ported to Drupal 8 but it can parse Drupal 8 modules.

You can install it as a drush command instead of a drupal module and then it should work fine on your Drupal 8 module.

What that doesn't support yet is extracing existing translations from a running site. Looks like people are working on a port in https://www.drupal.org/node/2356469 which supports that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The proposed solution (downloading the Drupal 7 module to use the Drush command) didn't work for me, but I did get it to work with the kgaut/drupal-potx module. Doesn't sound like the best solution yet, but at least it works..